# It's posible to create an AR app using google cardboard?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-cardboard

My idea is to have an AR app where the user can use both hands, so i thought using google cardboard  but i dont find any resource where it explains how to create a sample AR app for google cardboard

I followed [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart?hl=en) but i wasnt able to make the scene the real world instead of the scene that google provides as sample, i just see black.